# Thread safe logging class implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, thread-safety

Would the following be the correct way to implement a fairly straightforward thread-safe logging class?

I know that I never explicitly close the `TextWriter`, would that be a problem?

When I initially used the `TextWriter.Synchronized` method, it did not seem to work until I initialized it in a static constructor and made it readonly like so:

```
public static class Logger
{
    static readonly TextWriter tw; 

    static Logger()
    {
        tw = TextWriter.Synchronized(File.AppendText(SPath() + "\\Log.txt")); 
    }

    public static string SPath()
    {
        return ConfigManager.GetAppSetting("logPath"); 
    }

    public static void Write(string logMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            Log(logMessage, tw);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            tw.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter w)
    {
        w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        w.WriteLine("  :");
        w.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
        w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");

        // Update the underlying file.
        w.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at log4net. http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html

Comment: A third party logging framework is definitely a good option...

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I'm going to take a completely different approach here than the other answers and assume you actually want to learn how to write better thread-aware code, and are not looking for 3rd party suggestions from us (even though you may actually end up using one.)

As others have said, you are creating a thread safe `TextWriter` which means calls to WriteLine are thread-safe, that doesn't mean that a bunch of calls to `WriteLine` are going to be performed as an atomic operation. By that I mean there is no guarantee that the four WriteLine calls are going to happen in sequence. You may have a thread-safe `TextWriter`, but you don't have a thread-safe `Logger.Log` method ;) Why? Because at any point during those four calls, another thread might decide to call `Log` also. This means your `WriteLine` calls will be out of sync. The way to fix this is by using a `lock` statement like so:

```
private static readonly object _syncObject = new object();

public static void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter w)    {
   // only one thread can own this lock, so other threads
   // entering this method will wait here until lock is
   // available.
   lock(_syncObject) {
      w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
          DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
      w.WriteLine("  :");
      w.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
      w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
      // Update the underlying file.
      w.Flush();
   }
}
```

So, now you have a thread-safe `TextWriter` AND a thread-safe `Logger`.

Make sense?

Comment: You should also ditch the `TextWriter.SyncTextWriter` if you are going this way. Every method call on `SyncTextWriter` takes a lock on the instance. This is not necessary if you are wrapping the calls to the `TextWriter` in your own Logger class`s methods. If you are passing a raw `SyncTextWriter` around you can deadlock like this: `lock(textWriter){ textWriter.WriteLine("test"); // oops deadlock`

Comment: Hey, if you are going to use it in performance-critical applications (threading is often about speed, yeah?) you can't let all threads to wait for all those WriteLine and Flush calls to complete! Personally I start a separate logging thread (per AppDomain) to work in background and use lock-free Producer-Consumer collection so that Log calls are very fast even with many active threads.

Comment: @vlad Sure, that's a nice optimization now that .NET has concurrent collections support (it did not in '11) -- but more to the point, the op asked for a "fairly straightforward" implementation. It's also more to do with showing the basics of locking strategies.

Answer (score 9):

Someone pointed me to this post while discussing some logging issues today. We already have pretty good answers here, but I'm adding my answer just to show a simpler version of the `Logger` class which does the exact same thing, in completely `Threadsafe` way.
One main thing to notice here is, no `TextWriter.Synchronized` is required for thread safety, as we are writing the file within a proper `lock`.

Note: This has already been discussed in the comments section of x0n's answer.

```
public static class Logger
{
    static readonly object _locker = new object();

    public static void Log(string logMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            var logFilePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\YourLogDirectoryHere", "Log.txt");
            //Use this for daily log files : "Log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt";
            WriteToLog(logMessage, logFilePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log log-exception somewhere else if required!
        }
    }

    static void WriteToLog(string logMessage, string logFilePath)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(logFilePath,
                    string.Format("Logged on: {1} at: {2}{0}Message: {3}{0}--------------------{0}", 
                    Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(),
                    DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), logMessage));
        }
    }
}
```

To log something, simply call as

```
Logger.Log("Some important event has occurred!");
```

And it will make a log entry like this

> Logged on: 07 October 2015 at: 02:11:23
>   Message: Some important event has occurred!
>       --------------------

Comment: this is the best answer according to me here

Answer (score 6):

While calling [TextWriter.Synchronized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized.aspx) will protect that single instance of `TextWriter`, it will not synchronize your writes so that one "Log" call stays together inside of the file.

If you call `Write` (or `Log` using the internal `TextWriter` instance) from multiple threads, the individual `WriteLine` calls may be interwoven, making your date and time stamps unusable.

I would personally use a third party logging solution that already exists for this.  If that is not an option, synchronizing this yourself (even with a simple lock) will likely be more useful than using the framework's `TextWriter.Synchronized` wrapper.

Comment: I'm fine with using a third party solution, but I still want to understand how thread-safe logging works. Regarding a lock though I could never find a clear resource on whether to lock the writer itself or some innocuous object, ie lock(object)? Couldnt get a lock solution to work previously.

Comment: @Sean: In general, I typically recommend locking on a private object - one created just for that purpose.  This is, in particular, important if the other objects (ie: the writer) are visible to *any* other object.  If they are, you don't want to lock on them.  Using a private object allows you to expose the object later without worry.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into this class (part of .NET 2.0), no need to "create" your own logger.  enables you to log to a text file, event view, etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx

Your "Log" method can look something like this (assuming there is an intermal member variable called 'traceSource'):

```
    public void Log(TraceEventType eventType, string message)
    {
        this.traceSource.TraceEvent(eventType, 0, message);
        this.traceSource.Flush();
    }
```

Supporting this is a config section that names the TraceSource and has some Config settings.  It is assumed that when you construct a TraceSource in your logger you are instantiating it with one of the trace sources named in the config.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="Sample" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="file"
         initializeData="C:\temp\Sample-trace.log"
         traceOutputOptions="DateTime"
         type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```

Also, don't make your logger static.  Instead, use Enterprise Library 5.0 Unity for Dependency Injection / IOC.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple method of instrumenting your code, the facility already exists within .NET:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx

Additionally, third party tools will give you robust solutions for logging; examples include [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), [nLog](http://nlog-project.org/), and the [Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/).

I really recommend not reinventing the wheel on this :)