# Share Single Instance of Class

Tags: c#, class

I'm working with a class library where each class must share a single instance of a logger class. The logger is not mine, i.e. it is a dll I reference. Sharing is necessary because all messages have to be appended to the end of the single log message file that gets created when the logger is instantiated.

I thought about passing the logger class by reference after it is instantiated but this leads to some very ugly dependencies.

I'm under the gun and don't have a lot of time to experiment. Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this? I'm thinking a static class might be the answer but any implementation I undertake will take some time and I don't want to head down a blind alley.

======================= UPDATE ===================

I decided this the quickest and cleanest way to handle this:

```
    public class Logger
{
    private static LoggerTool _loggerTool;

    public static void WriteLogMessage(string message)
    {

        if (_loggerTool == null)
        {
            // Create a new log file
            string logFileName = "LogFile-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");

            _loggerTool = new LoggerTool(logFileName);
        }

        _loggerTool.LogMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of Logger are you using for example.. `Log4Net`..?

Comment: look here for some good examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320393/how-to-create-a-class-which-can-only-have-a-single-instance-in-c-sharp

Comment: if you create your own Logger as well look here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195084/thread-safe-logging-class-implementation

Comment: Logger is client's proprietary code; all I have is a dll to reference. And I have to use it.

Comment: Thanks for everone's suggestions. Worked up something in the wee hours of the morning. I'll test it today and post the results

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Creating a static class, and implementing singleton pattern would definitely work for you although it is not the cleanest way to approach it. Because of the coupling it makes it more difficult to unit test, etc.

Alternative approach would be to use Dependency Injection container such as autofac.

Here is a quick tutorial where they create use simple logger class with DI:
http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/dependency-injection-beginners-guide/

Comment: DI is an excellent way of providing a single instantiation to all who require one, but might be a little involved for "under the gun" production!

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
public static class LogManager
{
    private static Lazy<MyLog> logLazy = new Lazy<MyLog>(() => new MyLog());
    public static MyLog Log
    {
        get{
            return logLazy.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
LogManager.Log.Warning("blah")
```

from anywhere in your code.