# Writing to a file from DLL in a thread safe way - but what happens if many programs use this DLL?

Tags: c#, dll

Imagine I have DLL which has class which writes data to file. Imagine also that class uses locks to makes sure that no two threads write to that file at the same time.

Now imagine I have two different programs A and B which **separately** use this DLL.

And in both cases path to the file where data is written to is same. In this case this is not thread safe anymore because both programs are writing to same file, am I right? **And the locks I mentioned in DLL help only when it is used from ONLY program A, and not from program B simultaneously, am I right?**

---

To put this question in a different way: My point is basically **if** there is ONLY ONE single copy of DLL loaded regardless if many different programs are using this DLL, then I am on the safe side, because the locks which I had in DLL will work - and not let different threads from all these programs to write to file in an out of syn way. Am I right?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: Simple C# locks, such as in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195084/thread-safe-logging-class-implementation

Comment: Simple C# locks are specific to a particular process. If you want cross-process locking, you want a named `Mutex`.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: I don't want cross process locking, first trying to find out if my reasoning about this topic was correct. So in this case it maybe that program A and program B will both try to write to same file and the locks I had in DLL won't protect threads from program B to write to same file - when at the same time program A was writing to file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the code runs thread-safe, since a thread of program A cannot change the state of a thread in program B. You'll not have problems of variables and objects being accessed simultaneously.

But you have a problem of accessing a global resource which cannot or should not be shared. There are ways of synchronizing programs as well, e.g. with an [IPCChannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (inter process communication, internally using a named pipe), a named [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) or an [EventWaitHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.EventWaitHandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can also use the file itself as a synchonization object, if only a single operation on the file is needed. See the [File.Open()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, especially with the [FileShare.None](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) option.

Simply access the file. If it is possible, then this process has access to the file. If it's not possible, opening the file will result in an exception. Wait until the file lock is released, then try again.

At the moment you are `lock`ing an object. A .NET object is created in (virtual) memory. Virtual memory is *not* shared between processes, so each process will have a different object that it locks on. Therefore, synchronization between processes is not possible with the `lock` statement.

Comment: My point is basically if there is ONLY ONE single copy of DLL loaded regardless if many different programs are using this DLL, then I am on the safe side, because the locks which I had in DLL will work - and not let different threads from all these programs to write to file in an out of syn way. Am I right?

Comment: @Quser: No. A `lock` works on an object. And an object lives in memory. And each program gets different memory. Even `static` won't help.

Comment: Ok so even though I had a static lock inside class A which was working well from protecting writes to a file from different threads, if ANOTHER program uses also class A (via DLL) and tries to write to file, the lock I mentioned in the beginning will not help here, because it fill be different lock already because this DLL was loaded by a different program now, am I right?

Comment: "Well, the code runs thread-safe, since a thread of program A cannot change the state of a thread in program B" -- Yes but in this case program A and program B are writing to SAME file and locks don't help anymore because different programs loaded the DLL, do you see what I mean?

Comment: " you can also use the file itself as a synchonization object"-how? i need just write

Comment: Thomas if FileShare.None is set, and one process is writing and another process wants to write too, ok this will not be allowed, but if first process finishes writing, then second process can write now??

Comment: @Quser: no, it'll not wait, it'll throw an IOException. Yes, when the first program finished writing and closed the file, the second program can access it

Comment: Yes I am interested in this  "Yes, when the first program finished writing and closed the file, the second program can access it"

Comment: Yes I am interested in this  Yes, when the first program finished writing and closed the file, the second program can access it""

Comment: @Quser: what is your code? It's hard to guess what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

The code in your DLL will be executed in each process that loads it.

I'm assuming you mean C# [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), which is process-local, so nothing is stopping both processes writing to the file simultaneously.

Your best best is to let the file system handle it. Open the file in a mode that prevents other processes from writing to it:

```
File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
```

Where [FileShare.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) specifies that subsequent attempts to open the file will succeed only for read access.

Comment: Ok so even though I had a static lock inside class A which was working well from protecting writes to a file from different threads, if ANOTHER program uses also class A (via DLL) and tries to write to file, the lock I mentioned in the beginning will not help here, because it fill be different lock already because this DLL was loaded by a different program now, am I right?

Comment: Yep. You need an interprocess locking mechanism, either one of those @Thomas mentions, or the filesystem.

Comment: if FileShare.None is set, and one process is writing and another process wants to write too, ok this will not be allowed, but if first process finishes writing, then second process can write now??